# Denormalized data modeling with Siena

Tags: java, google-app-engine, siena, datamodel

I am trying to create a simple app on GAE/J. The data model consists of a list of `notes`, each with a few `tags`.

In the relational world, this would be a many-to-many - since each `note` can have several `tags`, and every `tag` can "belong" to several `notes`. However, this doesn't fit GAE datastore environment very well. So, I'm considering saving with each `note`, its list of `tags` as well. If indexed properly, searching by tag should be quick too.

My question: How to model this using Siena? Documentation is sparse and I saw the examples, but got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siena doc is sparsed as I don't have time to work on it anymore... I'm busy on other projects and if anyone wants to contribute and maintain Siena, he/she's welcome ;)

Considering your question, yes you should use a simple List (aka properties list) which is managed by Siena and works in GAE.

Add a field such as : (no annotation)

```
List<String> tags
```

It should work!

Comment: I'm sorry if the comment about documentation sounded like a rant. I didn't mean to offend! Now, what if my tag is a model in itself and not just a String? Can I just do `List<Tag> tags`? I read about embedding and thought I should use `@Embedded` annotation with this. My understanding was that if you don't want `JOIN`s to be performed (the scenario that I described in my question), then one should use `@Embedded`. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not offended :D It's just that I'm sadly aware about it and can't work anymore on Siena as I did last year as I work on other projects... Concerning Tags, no you can't use List<Tag> but List<String> as GAE only manages primitive types for List properties. @Embedded would be a solution also but there are limitations in GAE about the number of updates you can do in an entity group (embedded entities). You can't modify this group more than 1times/sec. So I would advise you to use List<String> and write your Tag key as a String so that you can find the corresponding very easily.

Comment: Ok - I get it now. I'll probably stick to using simple `String`s as tags (that's what tags are anyway!). I still need to actually try out how the "Find notes with so-and-so tag" works out. I'll update my findings here.

Comment: I got this working - but still couldn't figure out one thing: The most efficient way to search for all `notes` which contain a given `tag`. In particular, how do I make the `filter()` method look inside the `List`?

Comment: read this (operator = searches in the list) http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty

Comment: Ah I see. As simple as that :)